# Phython - Selenium return class name inside another class

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to check / return the class name exists within another class name, here is my code so far which only returns the first value in the first span '1'.

```
TagListPost = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("-V_eO")

for k in TagListPost:
    print(k.text)
```

I know k.text will only return text values, I'm not sure what I need to do to return the nested class name '_1P1TY coreSpriteHeartSmall'.

I've also tried this:

```
PostType = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_1P1TY coreSpriteHeartSmall')

for j in PostType:
    Print(j)
```

I've had no luck, it doesn't return anything because it's obviously finding the class and returning the value store in the class which is null. The code above attempts to print the class handle but 'j' is empty.

[Link to HTML I wish to return values from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mntSX.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get `class` attribute values of nested elements try:

```
TagListPost = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("-V_eO")

for k in TagListPost:
    PostType = k.find_element_by_xpath('./span[@class]')
    print(PostType.get_attribute('class'))
```